# Хранение условий в строках

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eval

Есть вот такой объект, из которого берет данные vue для отрисовки. Понадобилось хранить строковые представления кусочков кода (условий) в нем. Я знаю, все про риски, но так нужно. В какой-то момент эти условия надо проверить, как это сделать? Контекст для eval по умолчанию window, как ему подсунуть то, что лежит в obj.vars?

```js
var obj = {
  vars : {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: false
    },
  /*еще много всего*/
  blocks: [
      {
        condition: "a<b",
        text: "foo"
      },
      {
        condition: "!c && a>3",
        text: "bar"
      }
    ]
 };
 
 var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      blocks: obj.blocks,
      vars: obj.vars
    },
    methods: {
      check: function(cond) {
        if (cond=="") return true; /*своя логика тоже должна быть*/
        let result = true;
        /*result = eval(cond) ?? */
        return result;
      }
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<p v-for="block in blocks" v-if="check(block.condition)">{{block.text}}</p>
</div>
```

Можно obj.vars записать в другом виде, если это поможет, например:

```
[{key:"a", value:5},{key:"b", value:6...]
```

Или в виде ассоциативного массива.

Comment: Вот как раз не хотелось бы, потому что obj будет формироваться не вручную

Comment: Если уж мы используем `eval`, то можно и про `with` вспомнить.

Comment: Или `new Function` — может так даже лучше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Отказ от ответственности.** **Вам не следует применять данный код на продакшене.**
>
> Это далеко не лучшее решение, есть все еще тысяча и один способ сломать этот код, он имеет давольно примитивную защиту (не может обращаться к глобальному scope или к DOM), но все еще можно устроить утечку памяти или получить доступ к URL или к хранилищам (IndexDB, LocalStorage, SessionStorage).
>
> В самом крайнем случае, если код Вы получаете от доверенного источника и уверены в безопасности его исполнения, то Вы должны использовать HTTPS, что бы условия не могли быть подделаны атакой [человек посередине](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

```js
var obj = {
    vars : {
        a: 5,
        b: 6,
        c: false
    },
    /*еще много всего*/
    blocks: [
        {
            condition: "a<b",
            text: "foo"
        },
        {
            condition: "!c && a>3",
            text: "bar"
        }
    ]
};

function runTrustedCode (variables = {}, code) {
    for (let name of Object.keys(variables)) {
        let regexp = new RegExp(`${name}`, 'g');
        code = code.replace(regexp, `this.${name}`)
    }

    return Function(`"use strict";const window=null;const document=null; return(${ code })`).call(variables);
}

console.log(runTrustedCode(obj.vars, obj.blocks[1].condition))
```